# A word for someone who shallowly emulates someone/something they wish to be like (but not tied to fads/popularism - not doing it fleetingly)

Tags: single-word-requests

To detail further; I'm looking for a word for someone who makes shallow attempts to be like someone or something they like or admire by doing nothing more than acting out the perceived actions, whilst making little to no effort to understand the deeper knowledge that facilitates those actions.

Basically a top-down approach to things, rather than a comprehension-based climb.

A good (possibly offensive) example might be the sorts of nerd-types who wear fedoras in attempts to be a 'gentleman' and invoke the kind of respect that goes along with it without understanding the finer points of what else actually creates that 'look' or description.

Comment: ***Wannabe, poser, imitator, pretender, neverweres*** (modeled after *hasbeens* etc).

Comment: I had considered these, but they aren't quite exactly what i'm after, but they do work.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth has marked this as a duplicate of the question "A word for somebody who supports things fleetingly and whilst they are popular" - it really doesn't seem as though this is the same question at all, only that the TYPES of people this question's answer might apply to could also venn into the types "A word for somebody who supports things fleetingly and whilst they are popular" might answer.

Comment: FYI @Edwin Ashworth, while I agree there are many similarities, not so sure this is a precise duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165460/a-word-for-somebody-who-supports-things-fleetingly-and-whilst-they-are-popular. In support, I point to the evocative "mental miss" quotation by the OP, in his comment on his accepted answer.

Comment: Your inclusion of 'emulates ... something', while rather puzzling, certainly licenses 'jumping on the bandwagon'. Not being able to play an instrument; not bothering to learn. Fleeting, shallow, superficial.

Comment: @Logan Then please [edit] the question and mention there that you have already considered so-and-so and they are not what you are looking for...

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. Such questions may be closed as lacking research effort until they are edited to include research. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) research effort as detailed above.

Comment: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cargo-culter**.
Ref [wikipedia:Cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)

Comment: hahaha oh damn, that's very good. This is pretty much exactly the sort of mental miss i was thinking of.

Comment: Oft quoted among Comp. Sci. practitioners, along with such other colourful abstractions as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging